# Dynamically change parent element tag on Vue JS 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

How do I switch between different parents element depending on a prop conditional, keeping its content the same?

Example: If `Item` has `isRouter` prop, it renders `router-link` with the needed attributes, otherwise it renders a simple `li` element.

```
/* Item.vue */

<router-link v-if="isRouter" tag="li" :to="to" active-class="is-active">
<li v-else>
    /* some html */
    <slot></slot>
    /* more html */
</li>
</router-link>

// View.vue
<list>
  <item isRouter to="/new">
    Breaking News
  </item>
  <item>
    Orange
  </item>
</list>
```

Is this possible to do? What approach do you advice me to follow?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to dynamically change the tag type like that. I think you would be fine if you made the `router-link` and `li` tags siblings with the `v-if` and `v-else` conditionals and each with a `slot` in them, though I haven't tested that. Something to try.

Comment: @obermillerk it's kind what' I've done so far, the problem is the inside content has much more content beside the `slot`, so there's some duplication :/

Comment: did you end up getting it working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so I actually did find a way to do what you want!

Using vue's `component` tag and `vbind:is` property (or `:is` shorthand).

```
<component :is="isRouter ? 'router-link' : 'li'" :to="to">
  <!-- repeated content -->
  <slot></slot>
  <!-- more repeated content -->
</component>
```

The `:is` property can be delegated to a computed property if you need. And be aware that any props you want to pass to the `router-link` will need to be defined for the `component` tag, but you can have these conditional as well if you don't want them on the `li`.

This is where I found it: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components
There's also a link there to more details about dynamic components if you need further reading.